# Token pelo Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

É possível gerar token e enviar para algum dispositivo android que solicita fazer cadastro no aplicativo pelo Firebase Auth?

Comment: Você já deu uma olhada [aqui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens?hl=pt-pt), [aqui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens?hl=pt-pt) e [aqui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth?hl=pt-pt)?

Comment: Ja vi , minha duvida gerou mais sobre esses links, eu entendi por esses links que tenho que criar um servidor proprio para gerar o token.
Tipo, criar um servidor rest que gera o codigo e envia para o meu dispositivo. Estranho pq achei q o Firebase resolveria tudo isso, nao é a proposta deles?

Comment: Sim, essa é proposta deles. Você não precisa criar um servidor próprio. Pode utilizar [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://medium.com/@rosariopfernandes/firebase-cloud-functions-f6ed3787fa8d). Essa ferramenta permite que você execute código NodeJS do lado do servidor (o Firebase que trata de configurar ele pra você. Você só precisa escrever o código). Mais detalhes [aqui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?hl=pt-pt)

Comment: Obrigado, vou fazer isso!!!